# linux memory zone information stats

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel

I am doing some research that need to leverage the Linux swapping stuff. I have added a new zone which is only for my usage, other applications or the kernel itself cannot allocate pages from that zone. When the zone has reached the swapping water mark, it triggers the kswapd and try to swap out some pages inside the zone. However, the problem is that all the usage statistics inside that zone are 0 (like `NR_INACTIVE_ANON`, `NR_INACTIVE_FILE`). Therefore the `kswapd` will skip that zone. I allocate memory from that zone by modifying the current `vmalloc` routine. I set the page flag as reclaimable. Also from the `/proc/pagetypes` output, I can see that all the allocated pages from my zone is reclaimable. I do not know why there's no statistics in my zone.

Here's the output of the zoneinfor:

```
nr_free_pages 752735
nr_inactive_anon 0
nr_active_anon 0
nr_inactive_file 0
nr_active_file 0
nr_unevictable 0
nr_mlock     0
nr_anon_pages 0
nr_mapped    0
nr_file_pages 0
nr_dirty     0
nr_writeback 0
nr_slab_reclaimable 0
nr_slab_unreclaimable 0
nr_page_table_pages 0
nr_kernel_stack 0
nr_unstable  0
nr_bounce    0
nr_vmscan_write 0
nr_writeback_temp 0
nr_isolated_anon 0
nr_isolated_file 0
nr_shmem     0
```